# Python - Getting a new print of progressbar every update

Tags: python, progress-bar

I am completely new to Python and would like to display a progress bar while copying data from one database to another (MongoDB). What I am trying to get is a single progressbar displaying the advancement (percentage) of the copy of a database to another. The copy is working just fine, the problem lies within the update of my progressbar, which gets reprinted every loop.

Here is the script :

```
    coll_names = db_in.collection_names()
    db_in_size = db_in.command('dbstats')['dataSize']

    bar = progressbar.ProgressBar(max_value=db_in_size).start()
    for X in X_list:        
        for coll in coll_names:
          db_out_size = db_out.command('dbstats')['dataSize']
          bar.update(db_out_size)
          db_out[coll].delete_many({'X': X})
          data_in = db_in[coll].find({'X': X})
          if data_in.count() > 0:
                db_out[coll].insert_many(data_in)
    bar.finish()
```

X_list contains strings.

This code is certainly not optimized nor formatted the right way to display a single progressbar, but please bear with me.

Expected result : [Single progressbar on one line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUQ1I.png)

Current result : [One progressbar print for every iteration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brEFw.png)

Current result : [tqdm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6b4y.png)

Thanks in advance for any input you may have.

Comment: take a look at [tqdm](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tqdm). Personally I find it best progress bar. Aside from that any `print()`  call in loop body would mess things up with any progress bar library. It's also possible your terminal simply doesn't support control symbols.

Comment: Thank you. I actually tried to use tqdm with similar results. I will add it to my post. The terminal was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Progress bars work by printing a "\r" character (a carriage return) which moves the cursor back to the start of the line. This works as long as the cursor stays on the current line. What is probably happening here is you are printing a newline to stderr somewhere else in the code. This essentially means the carriage return has no effect. Or maybe you are using a terminal which doesn't support carriage returns (some IDEs apparently).

Comment: Seems like it was only a terminal issue, thanks for the quick answer. I tried the examples.py in the console and got the same issue. Had been looking all over for a fault within my code, my IDE's plugin compatibility did not even cross my mind